# Scroll only middle contents under sub heading within sticky header and footer in CSS flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to CSS flexbox I got this problem when I responsive my web page as given below.

[image]

Here you can see the black orange and red footer section should be sticky. In my code below I shrink them all and set HTML height as 100vh and body height to 100%. Because the given preview shouldn't be scrolled (sticky to window size) and only I want to scroll here us content which named as C.

I set content which class name **list** as `overflow: auto` but it does not work. I could able to do this in pio CSS. But I want to use flexbox so how can I do this? HTML and CSS codes are showing given below.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.arrow {
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.heading {
  height: 50px;
  background: chocolate;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.mainContent {
  background: aquamarine;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.box {
  background: wheat;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.list {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="arrow">
    </div>
    <div class="heading">
    </div>
    <div class="mainContent">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="subheading">
          <h4>background
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
          It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum
          passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="subheading">
          <h4>materials</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="list">
          random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
          a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      footer
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

**First solution :** Grid & display: contents 
I define a grid container (could be the body) with

```
height: 100vh;
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px) repeat(2, 50px 1fr) 10px 100px;
```

I set `main` and the boxes (`.box`) to `display: contents;`, this way the grid apply directly to the sections content.
With this set up `p.list` height is set to 1fr and I can set `overflow-y: scroll;` on it.
I didn't know how to set some bottom padding on the last section (as i removed its 'box') so I added a 10px row and defined the footer placement with `grid-row-end: -1;`. (Note : adding a `div` of 10px after each `p` tag, or a 10px bottom margin to the paragraphs were other options).

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: wheat;
}

html,
body,
div,
p,main,
.subheading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 50px) repeat(2, 50px 1fr) 10px 100px;
}

main.mainContent {
  display: contents;
  background: aquamarine;
}

.arrow {
  background: black;
}

.heading {
  background: chocolate;
}

.footer {
  background: red;
  grid-row-end: -1;
}

section.box {
  display: contents;
  background: wheat; 
}

.subheading {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: wheat;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
        <div class="arrow">
        </div>
        <header class="heading">
        </header>
        <main class="mainContent">
            <section class="box">
                <h4 class="subheading">background
                </h4>
                <p class="list">
                    It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
                    Richard
                    McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more
                    obscure
                    Latin
                    words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum
                    passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
                    source.
                    Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes
                    of
                    Goo.
                    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                    text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy
                    text
                    ever
                    since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
                    specimen
                    book. It has survived not only five
                    centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                    popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and
                    more
                    recently with desktop publishing software like
                    Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact
                    that
                    a
                    reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of
                    using
                    Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
                    normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look
                    like
                    readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their
                    default
                    model text, and a search for 'lorem
                    ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the
                    years,
                    sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from?
                    Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum
                    is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making
                    it
                    over
                    2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
                    up
                    one
                    of the more obscure Latin words,
                    consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical
                    literature,
                    discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de
                    Finibus
                    Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of
                    Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very
                    popular
                    during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a
                    line
                    in
                    section 1.10.32. The standard chunk
                    of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and
                    1.10.33
                    from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form,
                    accompanied
                    by English versions from the
                    1914 translation by H. Rackham. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                    industry.
                    Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown
                    printer
                    took a
                    galley of type and scrambled
                    it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                    electronic
                    typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                    Letraset
                    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
                    passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
                    of
                    Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the
                    readable content of a page when looking
                    at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of
                    letters,
                    as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop
                    publishing packages and web page editors
                    now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many
                    web
                    sites
                    still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident,
                    sometimes
                    on
                    purpose (injected humour and the
                    like). Where does it come from? Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
                    It
                    has
                    roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard
                    McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney
                    College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum
                    passage,
                    and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
                    Lorem
                    Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32
                    and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in
                    45
                    BC.
                    This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line
                    of
                    Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit
                    amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the
                    1500s is
                    reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et
                    Malorum"
                    by
                    Cicero are also reproduced in their
                    exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
                </p>
            </section>

            <section class="box">
                <h4 class="subheading">materials</h4>
                <p class="list">
                    random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000
                    years
                    old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of
                    the
                    more
                    obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
                    a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered
                    the
                    undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et
                    Malorum"
                    (The Extremes of Goo. Lorem Ipsum is
                    simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's
                    standard
                    dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
                    make
                    a
                    type specimen book. It has survived
                    not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially
                    unchanged.
                    It
                    was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
                    and
                    more
                    recently with desktop publishing
                    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem
                    Ipsum
                    is
                    not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it
                    over
                    2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
                    a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin
                    words,
                    consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical
                    opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop
                    publishing
                    packages and web page editors
                    now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many
                    web
                    sites
                    still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident,
                    sometimes
                    on
                    purpose (injected humour and the
                    like).There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered
                    alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly
                    believable.
                    If you are going to use a passage of
                    Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All
                    the
              tin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures,
                    to
                    generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from
                    repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic
                  atin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures,
                    to
                    generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from
                    repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic
                    words etc.
                </p>
            </section>
        </main>
        <footer class="footer">
            footer
        </footer>
    </div>
```

**Second solution** (heavy) **:** Fraction of 100vh
If you don't want your `body` to scroll, you can set your body to `height: 100vh;` (like you did) and every other box with a `height` a fraction of 100vh (and suming up to 100vh at the end). If you want to be sure your layout work that way, add `overflow: hidden` on your body. If you are missing bits, you are still over 100vh total.
It can be somewhat improved by using variables and calc() to set the heights values.
I modified your code a bit and removed the flex parts as i didn't use them.

```css
    html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
}

html,
body,
div,
p,
.subheading {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.arrow {
  position: relative;
  height: 10vh;
  background: black;
}

.heading {
  position: relative;
  height: 10vh;
  background: chocolate;
}

.mainContent {
  position: relative;
  height: 70vh;
  background: aquamarine;
}

.footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 10vh;

}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35vh;
  background: wheat;
  padding: 1vh;
}

.subheading {
  position: relative;
  height: 5vh;
  line-height: 5vh;
}

.list {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 28vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding: 0 1vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="arrow">
    </div>
    <header class="heading">
    </header>
    <main class="mainContent">
        <section class="box">
            <h4 class="subheading">background
            </h4>
            <p class="list">
                It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard
                McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure
                Latin
                words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum
                passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable
                source.
                Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of
                Goo.
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy
                text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
                ever
                since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
                book. It has survived not only five
                centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was
                popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more
                recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Why do we use it? It is a long established fact that
                a
                reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of
                using
                Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less
                normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like
                readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their
                default
                model text, and a search for 'lorem
                ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years,
                sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like). Where does it come from?
                Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum
                is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it
                over
                2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up
                one
                of the more obscure Latin words,
                consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical
                literature,
                discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
                Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of
                Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very
                popular
                during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
                in
                section 1.10.32. The standard chunk
                of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and
                1.10.33
                from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form,
                accompanied
                by English versions from the
                1914 translation by H. Rackham. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
                industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
                took a
                galley of type and scrambled
                it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into
                electronic
                typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of
                Letraset
                sheets containing Lorem Ipsum
                passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldu
                now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web
                sites
                still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes
            obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum
                passage,
                and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
          
                amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32. The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is
                reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum"
                by
                Cicero are also reproduced in their
                exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.
            </p>
        </section>

        <section class="box">
            <h4 class="subheading">materials</h4>
            <p class="list">
                random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years
                old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the
                more
                obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
                a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
                undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et
                Malorum"
                (The Extremes of Goo. Lorem Ipsum is
                simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem
                recently with desktop publishing
                software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum
                is
                not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over
                2000 years old. Richard McClintock,
                a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words,
                consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical
                literature,
                discovered the undoubtable source.
                Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of
                Good
                and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular
                during
                the Renaissance. The first line
               
                by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the
                1914
                translation by H. Rackham.It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable
                content of a page when looking at
                its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters,
                as
                opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop
                publishing
                packages and web page editors
                now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web
                sites
                still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes
                on
                purpose (injected humour and the
                like).There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered
              
                first
                true generator on the Internet.
                It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to
            
                 alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly
                 believable.
                 If you are going to use a passage of
                 Lorem Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All
                 the
                 Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the
                 first
                 true generator on the Internet.
                 It uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to
                 generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from
                 repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic
                 words etc.
            </p>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
        footer
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: let's assume I added fixed height (200px) to list class. yes it's scroll able. But not responsive any more. I want to identify exact height according to parent element and set there heights according to them

Comment: I removed most of my post and did a big edit on the code, setting every height value to vh

Comment: Finally I think i found a ''proper'' solution with grid

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the `overflow:hidden;` property  to your `body` tag, and the `overflow:auto;` property  to `.mainContent` class.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `position: sticky` like so:

1. Wrap `.arrow` and `.heading` in `.header`
2. Make `.header` and `.footer` sticky positioned with `top` and `bottom` specified, in this case 0
3. Remove `height: 100%` from `.parent` for the sticky elements to 'stick'

P.S.  - I've duplicated the content to add some height to the container

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.arrow {
  height: 50px;
  background: black;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.heading {
  height: 50px;
  background: chocolate;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.mainContent {
  background: aquamarine;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.footer {
  background: red;
  height: auto;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  align-self: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  background: wheat;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.list {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="heading"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="mainContent">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="subheading">
        <h4>background
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum
        passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="subheading">
        <h4>materials</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
        a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="subheading">
        <h4>background
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum
        passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="subheading">
        <h4>materials</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
        a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="subheading">
        <h4>background
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum
        passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="subheading">
        <h4>materials</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
        a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="subheading">
        <h4>background
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum
        passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="subheading">
        <h4>materials</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from
        a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Goo
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. but I didn't got exact answer. footer it should be exact height so I set height as 100px. It's ok. but content which I mean here without sub headings(background & material) they also keep same position without scroll.